# Extract multidimensional associative array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [accountID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 412216
            [1] => 396408
            [2] => 522540
        )

    [mailBody] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'We are glad to have contact you'
            [1] => 'Thank you for your cooperation'
            [2] => 'One of our customer service representatives will contact you soon'
        )

    [mailAttachments] => Array
        (
            [0] => 'URL1'
            [1] => 'URL1'
            [2] => 'URL1'
        )

)
```

This array pulls some information from a mailing box. I would like to extract each accountID with equivalent mailBody and mailAttachments as well.
Your response is highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too vague. What have you tried? What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Not beautiful but works (if I understand your purpose correctly):

```
$mails = array();
for ($i = 0, $cnt = count($array['accountID']); $i < $cnt; $i++) {
    $mails[] = array(
        'accountId'       => $array['accountID'][$i],
        'mailBody'        => $array['mailBody'][$i],
        'mailAttachments' => $array['mailAttachments'][$i]
    );
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be best practice to assign the length of the array to a variable $len = count($array['accountID']);  ??

Comment: @AndreDublin That is exactly what I'm doing there with `$cnt`.

Comment: @Niko But it seems that each time you run the for loop you run the count() function every time the loop iterates.  Not sure how it would equate performance wise with the count() set outside the for loop rather than inside.

Comment: @AndreDublin Believe me, it's executed exactly once - the syntax of a for loop is `for(a;b;c)`, and a is executed once when entering the loop - right? And you usually put there code that initializes variables that are used for the counting. I used a comma there to put two commands in a, so that b (the condition) is only the `$i < $cnt` part while a is both `$i = 0` and `$cnt = count(...)`.

Comment: @Niko ah I see, didn't notice the comma there.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function build in for this, names [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map). If the callback is `NULL`, a combination of the array like you need it is created. As I'm lazy, I'm using [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) to pass the parameters to the function.

`$array` is you array:

```
$arranged = call_user_func_array('array_map', array(NULL) + $array);
```

Comment: This is a neat solution, but definitely requires a comment to prevent confusion about what the hell is happing there ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mails = array_map(function ($id, $body, $attachments) {
             return compact('id', 'body', 'attachments');
         }, $array['accountId'], $array['mailBody'], $array['mailAttachments']);
```

It's important to note that this syntax requires PHP 5.3.

This rearranges the array so all items belonging together are in an array. You can then loop through the array and do whatever you need with it.

```
foreach ($mails as $mail) {
    // use $mail['id'], $mail['body'], $mail['attachments'] ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving the time to me

Answer (score 0):

Use the array indexes.

```
$i = 0
$accountID[$i];
$mailBody[$i];
$mailAttachments[$i];
```

But a better design would be to wrap all of these variables into one array if possible. Something like:

```
$accounts = array();
$account = array(
                  "id" => "",
                  "mailBody" => "",
                  "mailAttachments" => "",
                );

$accounts[] = $account;
```